# Which configuration parameters are available for creating a JsonWriterFactory?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

Check out this code I saw on the [Java ee tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp006.htm)

```
    /* Write formatted JSON Output */
    Map<String,String> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, "");
    JsonWriterFactory factory = Json.createWriterFactory(config);

    StringWriter stWriterF = new StringWriter();
    try (JsonWriter jsonWriterF = factory.createWriter(stWriterF)) {
        jsonWriterF.writeObject(model);
    }
    documentJsonFormatted = stWriterF.toString();
```

We are creating a `JsonWriter` to write to a string buffer `StringWriter`. Normally we can just create a `JsonWriter` directly from the `Json` class, but this doesn't format the JSON object properly. We specify a `config` variable to the `createWriterFactory` method, now as far as I know, this is the only configuration we can create. What other configuration parameters can we put into the `config` map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only constant field values defined by the JSON-P spec is the one you already have listed (`JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING`), according to:

https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.2

What sort of pretty printing are you looking for?  And what JSON-P implementation are you using?

I tried the following code:

```
    JsonObject model = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("foo", "bar")
                    .add("boo", "baz")
                    .build();
    /* Write formatted JSON Output */
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, "");
    JsonWriterFactory factory = Json.createWriterFactory(config);

    StringWriter stWriterF = new StringWriter();
    try (JsonWriter jsonWriterF = factory.createWriter(stWriterF)) {
        jsonWriterF.writeObject(model);
    }
    System.out.println(stWriterF);
```

Which resulted in a pretty-printed JSON string:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "boo": "baz"
}
```

(Here I used `org.glassfish:javax.json:1.1.+` as my JSON-P impl)

Comment: Yea it prints the JSON in a human readable form. I was just wondering if there were any other "constant field values defined by the JSON-P spec."

Comment: as far as the spec goes, there is just the 1 option for pretty printing. However, you can discover provider-specific options in a spec-standard way using https://static.javadoc.io/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax/json/stream/JsonGeneratorFactory.html#getConfigInUse--